# MS Form Recognizer Tool Create Project

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

When creating new Form Recognizer project, getting this error:
I was working on this project last month and now cannot create new project or access existing proejct.

[Error Message S-Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yUFk.png)
How to fix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you share an Azure blob storage path, you have to set an expiration date of such access. The error message indicates that such shared access has expired.  You need to re-share the blob storage path.  Please refer to the readme file of our FoTT tool for more details.

-xin
[MS Azure Form Recognizer Team]

Comment: Thanks , there are lots of storage paths!! which leads to individual files..  finally found Under Storage Account, "storage Explorer (preview) right click, get shared access signature.

Comment: it seems you're using the web portal to share?  you could also try to use Azure Storage Explorer App to browse and share.

Comment: Thanks will try this desktop application...